# More Precise PathSmoothing

Tags: xna, c#, c++, path-finding, graph

I'm reading a book about AI - Path planning and path smoothing. Yet this book is using c++ code. And i'm coding in c# with the XNA framework.

I have a path smoothing working, yet the book says it can be more precise (but being a bit slower).

This is the code i have until now:

```
    public static LinkedList<Vector2> SmoothPathEdgesQuick(LinkedList<Vector2> path, Player player)
    {
        LinkedList<Vector2> newLinkedList = new LinkedList<Vector2>();
        List<Vector2> toBeDeleted = new List<Vector2>();

        var edge1 = path.First;
        var edge2 = path.First.Next;
        while (edge2 != null && edge2.Next != null)
        {
            if (player.CanWalkBetween(edge1.Value, edge2.Next.Value))
            {
                toBeDeleted.Add(edge2.Value);
                edge2 = edge2.Next;
            }
            else
            {
                edge1 = edge2;
                edge2 = edge2.Next;
            }
        }
        foreach (var vector2 in path)
        {
            if (toBeDeleted.Contains(vector2))
                continue;
            newLinkedList.AddLast(vector2);
        }
        return newLinkedList;
    }
```

And this is working as it should work.
But the book says it can be more precise by using this code:

```
void Raven_PathPlanner::SmoothPathEdgesPrecise(Path& path)
{
  Path::iterator e1, e2;

  e1 = path.begin();

  while (e1 != path.end())
  {
    e2 = e1; 
    ++e2;

    while (e2 != path.end())
    {
      if ( (e2->Behavior() == EdgeType::normal) &&
            m_pOwner->canWalkBetween(e1->Source(), e2->Destination()) )
      {
        e1->SetDestination(e2->Destination());
        e2 = path.erase(++e1, ++e2);
        e1 = e2;
        --e1;
      }

      else
      {
        ++e2;
      }
    }

    ++e1;
  }
}
```

Somehow i don't know how to update my original code to the one below to make my pathsmoothing more precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This took some figuring out for myself, but I've got one for you.

Note that in the if statement we have no changes to `path` (since nothing is removed from it). Now `edge2` is changed it it's next every iteration, removing the need of the `else` statement.

I added `nextEdge1Spot` to avoid checking whether an edge has been deleted or not.

```
public static LinkedList<Vector2> SmoothPathEdgesPrecise(LinkedList<Vector2> path, Player player)
{
    LinkedList<vector2> newLinkedList = new LinkedList<Vector2>();
    List<Vector2> toBeDeleted = new List<Vector2>();

    var edge1 = path.First;

    while (edge1.Next != null)
    {
        var edge2 = edge1.Next;
        var nextEdge1Spot = edge1.Next;

        while (edge2 != null && edge2.Next != null)
        {
            if (player.CanWalkBetween(edge1.Value, edge2.Next.Value))

                //'Delete' all the skipped edges.
                var tempValue = edge1.Next;
                while (!tempValue.Equals(edge2))
                {
                    toBeDelete.Add(tempValue);
                    tempValue = tempValue.Next;
                }

                //Also delete edge2.
                toBeDeleted.Add(edge2);

                //Next time edge1 has to start here.
                nextEdge1Spot = edge2.Next;
            }

            edge2 = edge2.Next;
        }

        edge1 = nextEdge1Spot;
    }

    foreach (var vector2 in path)
    {
        if (toBeDeleted.Contains(vector2))
            continue;
        newLinkedLast.AddLast(vector2);
    }

    return newLinkedList;
}
```

Personally I would do the same as what the book does, removing nodes from the list you receive. But this should align well with your current code.

Hope it helps! :)